# Is there an accurate 3D CAD model of the version B board?

Tags: case, pi-models

I'm making a custom case for the Raspberry Pi and need a CAD model that is accurate to work with.

I've seen a few of them on [GrabCAD](http://grabcad.com/), but I'm uncertain if those are good enough. Are there no official CAD files of the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look on the [Raspberry Pi Wiki Resources](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Hub#Resources), under *Documentation* you will find 3D CAD files:

> ### RPi Model B 3D CAD files
>
> Theses are various 3D CAD Versions in both RAR and ZIP.
>
> - [CATIA V5 RAR](http://sdrv.ms/JqdhMb)
> - [CATIA V5 ZIP](http://sdrv.ms/LjyLGD)
> - [ProE RAR](http://sdrv.ms/KCv1hZ)
> - [ProE ZIP](http://sdrv.ms/KCvhxq)
> - [STEP RAR](http://sdrv.ms/KCvv7T)
> - [STEP ZIP](http://sdrv.ms/JMhv18)
> - [SketchUp](http://scc.jezmckean.com/item/581)
> - [SketchUp8](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=327d6b1d8bd6130d6fbd6b70c7f1d3e0)
> - [Eagle 5](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=4457)

I would say those are the "official" 3D CAD files.  You can cross reference some of the dimensions from the [Raspberry Pi's FAQ](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs):

> ### What are the dimensions of the Raspberry Pi?
>
> The Raspberry Pi measures 85.60mm x 56mm x 21mm, with a little overlap
>   for the SD card and connectors which project over the edges. It weighs
>   45g.

Answer (score 0):

There are [CAD Models on Grabcad](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-3-reference-design-model-b-rpi-raspberrypi-raspberry-pi-1) that are made around the official documentation:

[image: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B 3D CAD]